# Configure PostgreSQL DB with Vapor 3 on Heroku

Tags: swift, heroku, heroku-postgres, vapor

I've built a simple Vapor 3 API that I'd like to deploy on Heroku. I'd like it to be backed by a PostgreSQL database which is also attached to another Heroku app (I have successfully attached the DB in the Heroku dashboard – and the DB works correctly in the other application). However, my Vapor app never completes starting up, crashing with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Error raised at top level: ⚠️ PostgreSQL Error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[the IP addr]", user "[heroku postgres username here]", database "[heroku psql db here]", SSL off
- id: PostgreSQLError.server.fatal.ClientAuthentication
```

I used `vapor heroku init` to set up the Heroku app. I've Googled around, and tried adding a `Procfile` and messing with `configure.swift`, but so far no luck. Here are all the relevant files I can think of:

Procfile:

```
web: Run serve --env production --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT --config:postgresql.url $DATABASE_URL
```

configure.swift:

```
import FluentPostgreSQL
import Vapor

/// Called before your application initializes.
public func configure(_ config: inout Config, _ env: inout Environment, _ services: inout Services) throws {
    /// Register providers first
    try services.register(FluentPostgreSQLProvider())

    var contentConfig = ContentConfig.default()

    /// Create custom JSON encoder
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    if #available(OSX 10.12, *) {
        jsonEncoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
    } else {
        jsonEncoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970
    }
//    jsonEncoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase

    /// Register JSON encoder and content config
    contentConfig.use(encoder: jsonEncoder, for: .json)
    services.register(contentConfig)

    /// Register routes to the router
    let router = EngineRouter.default()
    try routes(router)
    services.register(router, as: Router.self)

    /// Register middleware
    var middlewares = MiddlewareConfig() // Create _empty_ middleware config
    /// middlewares.use(FileMiddleware.self) // Serves files from `Public/` directory
    middlewares.use(ErrorMiddleware.self) // Catches errors and converts to HTTP response
    services.register(middlewares)

    // Configure a database
    let dbConfig: PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig
    if let url = Environment.get("DATABASE_URL"), let psqlConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(url: url) {
        dbConfig = psqlConfig
    } else {
        dbConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(hostname: "localhost", port: 5432, username: "admin", database: "development", password: nil)
    }
    let postgresql = try PostgreSQLDatabase(config: dbConfig)

    /// Register the configured SQLite database to the database config.
    var databases = DatabasesConfig()
    databases.add(database: postgresql, as: .psql)
    services.register(databases)

    /// Configure migrations
    var migrations = MigrationConfig()
    migrations.add(model: Visit.self, database: .psql)
    services.register(migrations)
}
```

Package.swift:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SubwayNyc",
    dependencies: [
        //  A server-side Swift web framework.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "3.0.0"),

        //  Swift ORM (queries, models, relations, etc) built on PostgreSQL.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-postgresql.git", from: "1.0.0"),

        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/sql.git", from: "2.1.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "App", dependencies: ["FluentPostgreSQL", "Vapor"]),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["App"]),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: ["App"])
    ]
)
```

How can I get PostgreSQL hooked up to my Vapor 3 app on Heroku?

Comment: Does `heroku config` in the non-working environment return the correct `DATABASE_URL`?

Comment: @davejagoda yes, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original error is the key here, in particular: `SSL off`.

This error is thrown by Heroku Postgres when the client is attempting to connect without SSL. Not familiar with Vapor myself, but a quick look around suggests that [configure.swift](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/getting-started/structure/#configureswift) is where you can make configuration changes. Once you enable SSL from the client, you should be able to connect to this database instance without issue.

Comment: Ah! Wonderful, don't know how I missed that. Thank you! (Now getting a different error, indicating that SSL can't connect, but hey, at least it's trying!)

Comment: Yeah, this might be an issue with Vapor itself (again, no expert myself). I did notice a couple PRs/issues around SSL support. You may wanna comment there to make sure it's officially supported.

Comment: 404 is found on the reference config. Would you please advise the updated solutions/

Comment: @RajuyourPepe I've updated to point at the updated configuration file but this project still doesn't appear to make much mention of SSL support. In the readme it does look like there's another project which uses `libpq` under the hood so you might have better luck with that.

Comment: WhAt is libpg at Heroku side?

Answer (score 3):

For Heroku we need unverifiedTLS transport.

*https://api.vapor.codes/postgresql/latest/PostgreSQL/Classes/PostgreSQLConnection/TransportConfig.html*

```
let pgURL = Environment.get("DATABASE_URL") ?? "postgres://user:password@host:port/database"

let pgConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(url: pgURL, transport: PostgreSQLConnection.TransportConfig.unverifiedTLS)!
```

:D